# Openresty nginx reload not working? (Updated variables are nil in lua file)

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I'm currently passing some new variables into my lua file, it seems like these new variables are `nil` when I log them out and I removed my old variable called `saveFileRootPath` but the old variable still can be logged.

Here is the a part of my nginx conf:

```
location /fileupload {
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
              #
              # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
              #
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,fileheader';
              #
              # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
              #
              add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
              add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
              add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
              return 204;
            }
            if ($request_method = 'POST') {
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,fileheader';
              add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
            }
            if ($request_method = 'GET') {
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,fileheader';
              add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
            }
            default_type text/html;
            set $fileSaveListingPath "C:\\Services\\openresty\\html_ecomm\\files\\listing";
            set $fileSaveDetailPath "C:\\Services\\openresty\\html_ecomm\\files\\detail";
            set $fileSaveZoomPath "C:\\Services\\openresty\\html_ecomm\\files\\zoom";
            content_by_lua_file lua/fileupload.lua;
        }
```

Added 3 new variables `fileSaveListingPath`, `fileSaveDetailPath` & `fileSaveZoomPath` which are logged as `nil`.

Removed the old variable `fileSaveRootPath` but still can be logged.

I feel like maybe theres a cache? Cache is turned off, afaik.

Here is the upper part of my lua file:

```
local http = require "resty.http"
local upload = require "resty.upload"
local cjson = require "cjson"
local saveRootPath = ngx.var.fileSaveRootPath
ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "TEST: "..ngx.var.fileSaveRootPath )
local chunk_size = 4096
local form, err = upload:new(chunk_size)
if not form then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to new upload: ", err)
    ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
end

form:set_timeout(1000)

function file_exists(name)
   local f=io.open(name,"r")
   if f~=nil then io.close(f) return true else return false end
end
```

As you can see from the code, `ngx.var.fileSaveRootPath` I tried to log it and it still can be logged for some reason. This is from server side btw, so I don't want to simply restart the entire server.

PS:
`nginx -s reload` didn't work for me.

Some error logs:

```
2018/03/12 11:42:45 [info] 10660#10372: *4506 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 124.13.241.136, server: 0.0.0.0:16001
2018/03/12 11:44:40 [error] 10660#10372: *4508 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: ./lua/fileupload.lua:9: attempt to concatenate field 'fileSaveListingPath' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
    ./lua/fileupload.lua: in function <./lua/fileupload.lua:1>, client: 124.13.241.136, server: db.hkltd.com, request: "POST /fileupload/ HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx.com:16003", referrer: "http://localhost:3000/catalogmanagement/8868"
2018/03/12 11:45:43 [info] 10660#10372: *4514 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 124.13.241.136, server: 0.0.0.0:16003
2018/03/12 11:58:16 [error] 10660#10372: *4516 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: ./lua/fileupload.lua:9: attempt to concatenate field 'fileSaveListingPath' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
    ./lua/fileupload.lua: in function <./lua/fileupload.lua:1>, client: 124.13.241.136, server: xxx.com, request: "POST /fileupload/ HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx:16003", referrer: "xxx.com:16003/catalogmanagement/8868"
```

Comment: Just a guess -  If NGINX couldn’t successfully apply the new configuration, it continues to work with an old configuration (saved somewhere). It may explain why you still can see old variables.Please provide error log file, it may help.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there's only one place where we keep the nginx.conf (searched the entire hard disk). Any ideas?

Comment: Provide error logs

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler Added some logs

Comment: Do you use Docker to run your nginx?

Comment: If you mount nginx.conf as a file - the changes may not be reflected within container. https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1392

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/644892/nginx-set-variable-in-location).

This part: `The immediate consequence is that you can't use custom variables in an http block.`

Seems like I tried to set my own custom variables but you can't actually do that in nginx conf file afaik.

My solution was to just set my locations in the lua file and things were fine.

PS:

`nginx -s reload` works as it should. I added a couple of server entries and the reload worked fine.